# Execution plan and SQL goes to hung state

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-administration

I am using a SQL server 2008, which has databases mirrored in Synchronized mode.

I am trying to run some update stored procedures, with some nested joins and it runs fine (Obviously with a reduced performance compared to a server which is not mirrored).

The problem I am facing is that if I select the "show detailed plan" option. The query starts running and it virtually goes to a hung state and doesnt recover. I finally end task the SQL.

I have a public role for the databases and I cant access any stats.

Can you tell me what exactly (or in general) should I ask the DBA to look at?

The details of the SQL server is mentioned below.

> Product - SQL Server Enterprise Edtn- 64 bit.

1. OS - WIndows NT 6.0
2. Memory -6143 MB
3. Processor -2
4. Maximum Server memory - 3072 MB
5. Minimum server memory - 16 MB

Any help on guiding me to a right direction will be appreciated.

Regards,
Dasso

Comment: 1) Is the actual execution plan or it's the estimated plan? 2) That stored procedure includes a cursor or while statement?

Comment: Hi @BogdanSahlean It is actual execution plan and it has a while loop, no cursor though. However if you are referring to while loop, I had the same procedure with Actual execution plan for another server, which is not mirrored and it worked fine, means it didnt hang, but its hanging everytime in this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because

1) You have activated [Include actual execution plan] option and because

2) There is a WHILE statement

SQL Server will send to client - Sql Server Management Studio the actual execution plan of every SQL statement executed by every iteration of WHILE statement. So, if WHILE includes a simple UPDATE and it executes 100 iterations then Sql Server will send the execution plan of UPDATE 100 times!

You should decrease the number of iterations for WHILE or you could use estimated plans.

Comment: I got what you were saying. However this was not the case with earlier SQL server 2005 version, atleast I could break the execution and see the plan, this in turn is virtually stuck forever!

Comment: @Dasso: If `WHILE` is executed just one time (one iteration) then you have the same problem ?